# Extend JUnit assertEquals

Tags: java, junit

I want to create a new `assertEquals` which takes in as input a custom pojo for expected and actual.

How would I go about extending `assertEquals` of the `JUnit library`?

What I could do is implement a compare method which  returns a boolean and have this as the input to the `assertEquals` or even `assertTrue` but creating my own `assertEquals` seems more elegant.

Would it simply be the case of returning true if equal or raising a AssertionError?

Comment: Why don't you just override equals (and hashCode of course) methods in your POJO and use `assertEquals(Object, Object)`. Isn't that an option?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just override equals/hashCode of your objects?

Comment: That sounds perfect actually.

Comment: You could also use a custom [Hamcrest `Matcher`](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial), which might be more expressive in the long run (and doesn't require `equals` to encapsulate everything you only care about in this POJO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Makoto commented, you could use a custom Hamcrest Matcher.

The disadvantage of the other common answer here (just change the definition of Object#equals for your class), is that you would have one and only one way of comparing your objects, and it would have to match exactly what is needed by the test rather than what would be needed by users of the class.  The two needs may or may not be identical.  Often in testing, I only need to assert one or two values, sometimes several, but usually not what gets tested by the "natural" #equals method of my class.  Furthermore, I work with a lot of classes that don't even have an explicit override of #equals.  In these cases you would have to define one that works simply for the case of your test, whereas it semantically might not represent the domain very well.

Answer (score 2):

There is [an overload of `assertEquals` that takes objects](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)).  It [(eventually) calls the `equals` method on both objects](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.10/org/junit/Assert.java#Assert.assertEquals%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29).  So, the "compare" method you need to write is an override of `Object`'s `equals` method.

Once you have that written, then you can call `assertEquals("Failure message", yourObject1, yourObject2)`.  There is no need to extend JUnit for this case.

As an aside, if you override `equals`, then you should override `hashCode` also, in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

Asserts are static methods, defined in `Assert` class. `TestCase` derives from that class, hence all asserts are available there too.

```
java.lang.Object
  |
  +--junit.framework.Assert
        |
        +--junit.framework.TestCase
```

1. Creating another derived class, such as `class MyTestCase extends TestCase` and define your customized asserts there the same way they are defined in `Assert`.
2. Use `MyTestCase` instead of `TestCase`
3. Profit!

Another approach is to define proper `equals()` method and use standard `assertEquals()`. You can use `EqualsBuilder` to get a reasonable implementation automagically using reflection.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html

If you don't like `Apache Commons`, you can find similar tool in `Guava`.

Comment: What you're describing is JUnit 3, which is out of date for years.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is not out of date. Ask Android folks - they are still actively using JUnit3, which is somewhat sad...

Nevertheless this solution will also work with JUnit4 fine. If you don't want to use derived `TestCase` you can always implement your customized `MyAssert.assertFancyStuff(Object a, Object b)` and use it the same way you usually used `Assert.assertEquals()` static methods. It's just easier.

Comment: And ... why would you do this?  If you're going to write your own `assertEquals` method, you can either put it in your test class itself, or just put it in some utility class.  Even if you have JUnit 3 (does ANYONE still use JUnit 3?), there's no need to introduce a whole new level into the class hierarchy.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, A LOT of Android folks still use it.

Yeah, I know that "Android Java is not Java" rant already.

Putting your asserts in a base class may or may not be useful. If your tests share some common stuff it's not a bad idea to put it in a base class.